# Is it good to automatically sign up a user if he doesn't have an account?

Tags: website-design, forms, registration

On some sites when you don't have an account, you are asked: "Sign in with Gmail" or "Sign in with Facebook". When you click and your account isn't found, it automatically signs you up using the selected social network, in other places like Stack Exchange for example: when you log in and you don't have an account: it ask you to confirm like below:

[image].

I am working on something and I am wondering which one will be the best practice.

Comment: It depends. Why are you having the users sign-up?

Comment: I am created an app and there are some options they can't see if they don't sign up or have an account

Answer (score 2):

If you ask for confirmation you make the user aware that login in in the site will create an account specific for that site (even if he is using facebook or gmail for the authentication); more important, in the confirmation (see your example image) the user is agreeing the privacy policy and terms of service at the confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

An absolute and resounding **Yes**. Every time you remove friction from the flow, your user experience is enhanced. Thus, if your content requires the user to be signed and you facilitate that process, then you're doing things right.

Think about how many people will leave your site because they don't want to follow a signup process, filling forms and such, and how many people will get to your site and actually interact with it because... *they are already signed!*

This is something me and my team do a lot, and both engagement, CTR and bouncing ratios are greatly improved every time we do it (as a matter of fact I implemented it just yesterday in one site, go figure). But just in case, take a read to http://www.nngroup.com/articles/login-walls/ to a more general view.

This answer has justy one caveat: this approach is good for general purpose sites. And while some sites using sensitive information use this approach (somehow), I'm not fully convinced, so if you need financial info or stuff like that, go with a better *non-automated* flow that doesn't make teh user think you actually know more about him than what you should (which in financial and sensitive apps is... *nothing*)

Comment: But how do you know that the user has agreed to your Terms of Service if s/he hasn't clicked an "Agree and Create New Account" button?

Comment: Please check this site's signup process and you'll have the answer. Also, you may not need any terms and conditions for many simple processes like posting in a board or being able to access certain content

Comment: Ah, interesting. So you could simply write near the "Sign up using Google" and "Sign up using Yahoo" buttons: "By registering, you agree to the [privacy policy](http://www.example.com/) and [terms of service](http://www.example.com/)." I'm not sure if this would hold up as well in a court of law, but as you've pointed out, it might be unnecessary for certain use cases anyway. OK; I've now upvoted your post.

Answer (score 1):

If your website provide something like quick service and you don't need a lot of data from the end user just basic authorization then you can go with facebook,twitter or google signup, because mostly now a days people uses the internet in their own laptop or pc and have fb or twitter already logged in and moreover people hate create a new account for ever other website so better use those 3rd party login /signup api and save both user and your time
Hope it helps